# processingFailure error (400) while retrieving CommentThreads list

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I a trying to retrieve all the comments of a video via Python iteration/paging. I am logged correctly with a developer key

```
import googleapiclient.discovery as gg
import googleapiclient.errors as gge

yt = gg.build(api_service_name= 'youtube', api_version= 'v3', developerKey = M_KEY)
comments= []
page= ''

while True:
        request = yt.commentThreads().list(
            part= "snippet,replies",
            order= "relevance",
            maxResults= 100,
            pageToken= page,
            textFormat= "plainText",
            videoId= video['id']
            # video is a static dictionary i've saved outside the script
        )

        try:
            response = request.execute()
            page= response['nextPageToken']
            comments.extend(response['items'])
            print('Comments extended')
        except KeyError:
            # there are no more pages
            print('Iteration ended')
            break
        except gge.HttpError as error:
            print('HTTP error:', error.__dict__['resp']['status'])
```

What i'm expecting it to do is iterate the pages of comments until the `response['nextPageToken']` throws a `KeyError`, meaning that there are no more pages of comments. Instead, what happens is that the execution goes flawlessly for a dozen of iteration (at best) then it starts to throw said `processingFailure` error which content looks like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.commentThread",
        "reason": "processingFailure",
        "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.",
        "locationType": "other",
        "location": "body"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>commentThread</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid."
  }
}
```

I have tried to log both the `page` and the `videoId` to ensure nothing went wrong with them but they're both valid. I've also tried to `time.sleep()` for up to 15 minutes when that error occurs but nothing changes.
This is the request in json format **at the time of the error**, catched using `request.to_json()`, thanks to [@stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) for suggesting it:

```
{
  "uri": "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads",
  "method": "POST",
  "body": "part=snippet%2Creplies&order=relevance&maxResults=100&pageToken=QURTSl9pM2xlemsyWjAzYlBhWkNRMTFMMWIyMjFsVVNnS2U0WE8zTkwxRzdRdkpsdlVqWHlwWEV2SmxkeUxjdkR1UWk3eVU1OTI1cmJEeUtJZHRGQWVmY21PUGxVOXBER3YtckE2NlhSWlRwQzR0Y2VyY0JDbC1uNVRaSU56RklzejJERmRCc2lLUjV2Rm1LV0Njc3ByMjliRXRMZmNjRFJucFgwNFNBYVhkSFJzYXkzNVpKTXNNSzNfWmVGd3dSRWxYQmwyQmxnWGJwNFZidVpiYjlOWjBabFFsalZFZkdqZFV0SHlrVEJqclppVnRtMjZCTnYtQm9WWjFrQ0dELUlLTnYwWG50cU5BQXJ3Ukh3VE9PZnNaZ0tZaWN1ZTdBakJkWFp5Ymo5M2R5Y0g1aWVsWUUzUVg0TU83Q2JZQ1IxWnRTMXUyTFhpSDdmMU9GTmtiQUE0UjdyVUVBelNnSjhTTDVsLU1TaERwVHdvSVhkX1ktNVBTc2xkX09zcjBOT3E3Z2lVWWRPRFhkVF9NN1JaQTEyUEJmU1hNbUtvM2JzU1NzOFRid29wTEo3Q0hucmJnNHcwNUJzaGtqSE8wa2g2U0FUY3pQbDJ1bGNnaFRKNEJCRm90TVNyWXNSREgyQVFqMU9PNnY3elBGSEhrYXJSMUJYS09yQ0tOVE5Oa3l5V00tdGY3TTlwY3o0VXJsaWRua1BrNXVhWmVLMzV1T2NmOEhqaUNucEdheTRfZjNiM1JkYUJuaGZqQjFMV1c0NFRJNXlzR2trdFpLemV1SU12V0tCTW11b1RMU05PXzA0eVdHM3lRclpZaC1BN3k4RDdhTW1uTHZtbDVsRzBVTVFHdkdkMTN4VHQzNW1tZ3BoY0F6VDJVWTFhUWpxdW8td1M0bnkzQTRtVGc5bGxQNV81ejV1dm1JX1ZDRVZIXzI3eXVnbHJBcC1Lb0NULUhHOGp3ZGNGeVFKbFNXbVh0Y2NQei1UbjBFLVhuZWp0eXh5NzVjOEtjS1FqTUppQWdOSDRmWWtSOUZPRHQtSEpsTnJtNWZVX2t4VDlVTDB6WmxWTHN5dlZzZllNQkFBOEJNMWZkOEtoTk5jMnQ4Y0hydXVScTNILXZLXzJodGFUNmxhQnEtay1PVV9yYzJFNEhKaDZjcUszV3ZGM2VLaUxJZjlwRmViYXRfVGRSOFZ6OF9vU2h6WjVqNkhVU0tqZHduLTNlaFhuTHFXSG1WSk1HUVQ4dkdIdDZvUFdKNkxOeFlhTmJzd1J4dGQzLXBHUmsxaHYtdFc2cTI1VDZsMWJGdE5Pb1RmR2hlRGM3cjZPcDJ2eTljQk1GcTJXaTFtNFhndzlWbDBOby1kNzZhLU5WNTI1VUlzRmpQSkRvSlFFMUQzNllzbi0tU01OYTg1a2poS2ZrWHpQMjQyd1hDb3h4blE5ZlJmN2xIMEstRFR6cUFWcTNDRDFfbjNubXY4Z2ZseGdVY2NjTWk0NzQ3SDFZcWs2eWxZWlB0Vl9iSldlbktOMjVFWUp6UnVRb3dfOXFQdmhBZEN5clJpX1g4aVhmdERnbE5XX1FjVWNXODRtSm1LSUpDVnJHVGlEeUtGb3BPMVYyWU5TbnQzY29NLUY5c3Y2WmpNVTNlVjIxQ2RwSzlKTUZwY0RxY2FlMGFtd2tucFpjeUtDN2xwOERYcDJwSU1RY0dIdXdCTmJIcWdjbTh1Q04wVTh1dktzeVdob09wX25uU19BMFNlRlBrNG1wZFRKVVJFVzVfdGQxbGFYemFqZjJOQTd1R0NCZ0RrMWlTS3BMMy1hY0FMd25KTGFYelJPQjZvRnlYMnBFelhCREgyRDJ3TnJWNldWUllqOVVvdHV2cVRXRXlBbkJpaFJpd3RIc2RaamVaUERldXItT1pkTVVFczBzNi1hZmhDYTFzWVM3SElsYkxtMkoybC03YlZVRkt1NEVSWV8tWHRJTko4d2hqWllWVU04UXlkQV84ZjFzVm01bW83cTd4R3ZOSVNabGRSaXVlTU91MXR6RVFYeTNwNHd3bzNVY1RncHdzY1VKQWw2eWNvcmdER0N5RjZiQkRmNnh0S256MzhreldFTm9XMDhlY1VUeEhnNTM2bHNYVlpKdGJrdHd1Y3VCc0hYOHlEc1EyZXJLTUlMTlVQb0FmU0hpdy1WdS1iT19fTTlMQUVWa3BnWloxSXdUZHotMW5zWWVnTVBzelE3VmQtRlBOajNfcmJJNnlZYkpDdmxKWXoxcjBZYkV4Q2duNGx1MTlrYWVVOXktT0lVX2dfVnc2cW9nSEVHSHZCUzFHRFFPaW1ydUxlY012bVQtaVBnTXQ1VWxOZVI3YW9nTkhFdHlwUGlneFdOM2Jkcm1iWEcxN25pQVI0TUpvVW1hemlrYWl6M0dnSTQ0VWhVWVMxaHEzeS05cnJRSkJ6TEVEZTB4anYySzR6WWhyMEtkZ0ZVMkxDZXlkcHFCSTBfU2Z3ZEVTYkE1YlE1SXI0M3lhUnJGZ1l0QVZFU2ZqRDE1MUhSLU1lU2dxWFpUem04RHVqOVBTUkZhbkFLWUJ2aGZsX0w2SzBabTBoUUxiYVZxT25ydk56U01YdklJZmtPemxtT0Nrc1JGOWVRQnMydk5lZkRjRExEUzRaWXFfTlNRdVNOUTFacFdLcklqRXc1NDg2eGU2NXlid3Y0SnRVeWplVE5CVVF4Qm01ajJfOWY2U2NWcWlVajYwYXJ3eXZ6RGt4cldCMndES0wzZ0xERl91bmlQaDVtUmNXSERXekJCVDAtd2ZnVFBadERnQlJWUEl3cWxCb3FfOEh2NkJCUlZqUThCMUk0OXM3Sjk3Sng3WFBpdUlEUFRnLV9kMnhoa2Z5QVpLRFNLSWl0ck1WUnhKRWFaZ0J0VDZmTjY3MG5SMkZQYUx0YTQ3dmgzYzhpa0Nua0dIS0VzSGYzOERiYkN4ZXM1ZkpkYV9nMEJrMnA2aHgycWFfZ04ySmRGellBaUphdXA2X213WXNxVW1QbUpfa2xZZTUwbVA2azMyRjV0Q2dRcWJVajFuVTFjRHB5QUZUcTZ1X3RwNGVBSmVoNWt6ajFZNTkwS1J2TzZreHhfQ1EzTTdDUGpCb0V1SXdFWmh6YjF0Q1NHUnoxTy11MURZak03ZnNEX0NCSUxPbkVuZGZ5VDlCMkkwNl9lLUw2bk05MUVfU29NTmg4WFBSSGNibnZ4T3h4T25Yal81a3NDMG5veDBERVdLRVBEV0pqRi1CbEpnV01HajhjR29jbXFEdXpIcFdCblcyZ2dsX1ZUNHJuMkxHUFV6ekZiaklFMXpob0w4MXJNOXVhZ2dMX1oxdzNkRi1sV3JDaGpING10b21qYTI0QW00dWFOOVZHSWJlT3lZVy1qSzNnUGxPU0hTZnFTS2VVLW80cHFqWTAtYV9lbHI5WHdnZV9nM25oX2Iwd2lUeXgxQndDcENrczUxb3RlZlZkSnREU20xSjdCM0VBZkZ4X1pkQ2YwQUszcWJxRVdwM25wM0w2WmpNTG1WM0RyWlU3TkpGeElBeGRkUTZlWEttazJuLW1mdFZtMTNVamRKZEthMkFfbS1HSnRtMFRTbFlVYnBqQ2puaUVrY2xieTB0TDF4UDNUWGNMUFo3enFtajB5T0dZbGRYQkxDQzlxdGNXN0d4V093RXUxd2Z4ek9oVEZzVUpabHpxeHNFVlVUbF9ORGk5U1BhVHg3QlJEWjdqM2g1VlFhb184SU1ZMERFLWJnY0htaXk2aXFoTjBMaUg2eTdjVmhHekFCbmdjNXJ2WkpQVE9jY09RRXE1SVJYenhvdVJxVGRDbnd5WGdrZnlyWG96T2FXcVRVRXBiWHBGRGFnZTUybmFJam1HanpPelNSZHBJLW5yaDgybm5BdldNNTRtcGNuaXRGbzJmODhyc2IzYmNUdDNoekNaRG5Oa2k1OUNXU2tuSnd2OG1GVjBGM2xid0lWd3QwWDR3Ukc4TlZZcXdkY2FOdS0xaWlsajAwQTBLVnJTVzljLS1WZF9WWGl0Y21naDdpX2c1djJwRFpuU3pWY1VNRWNOTy1GaVdSTUxDTHZ6VDFNYl9HRmsxVEZlTG5fVFdrNzRYdlpoSVRwMHJjSjdJT21lU09ObEtqTlNiX0FCNGtXRldpSHByY0htSGxOYS1JbWZWbWRCZUlLaFhxUG5haGZCMm1PbklDMGFJS0pmZ2RjUUtVSWpLeVBrTk5DMXo5VUVkeGZKRFRtZDh4OHJkV3BEbi0wUnJXY2x1Rk9XU04xeXpkbnA5U1FnV2huOTFYVlBGRG5Rem9CODdfRUU2d3liNy1LQ0JHbjFsVVRQc3pMS3JudjhDVG1Bb2xjYU1MaUprajZGT2dkS0ktd3IzNXZMSWhFQm9oamdGZW5KcWNOQ0Q5NDZGWXFzTE5peEVyenJHWG9ZaWtNRjVoUXJNVFVxdjhSYUgyRHZKcXpmOWtMRHJmV1dMRklLUTFvLVJZbDY5dzRFcXJxUGJoenF4SFpLYUFoOWpFcnNNWVZmMmsycy1YVXllMkhwNzJrOGl5eUpTTXdQVFhWTjJ4MVA1OC1FbnVlbGZSRDQwOWxkcUwwSkRWTFVHMUdhUi1jVnlBZVJKZmZNY3Z2OTQ4MVdqWDV5WFBvSjJJY25VZDdOc2JyUkRKQ1IybXY2NG5uX3NJUmJubXFvTHQ3dHVoV0pMQmRlb2tQOUU2cU1xN3gzVnFsMzVqVDhjSFNuSmNYZWczSG1veEhGWDlkTDNBRmtXVFhBaVQwSDR2dTJBaU1nRUJVZndMS3gzUjNXNlRRcGJqNnJkbldzT3FjdU1NSkwtOVZ2WEIzMEYtQlFFNW84dUthQjFvZFg4OVota255cWt5Mlo1cXpoWTJKel9vTmpLbHRlQVN0WkVURDh3WG8wSTY3OE0yTTF4OF9KQ3ctc1Uzd3hxejdyRlB0NzVXZkxKU1RvOUw1TWtEMjNCaWVaLTkzaExwTHlwaG9DaC1qcjE4cHgxRHRtMmc3TnZXaTJleHNHVW1WTzJlMkVlWFd6QUxfOENSUEJRU0E5d08xa2hjSkxBSG5kY1BlTzJxUkR0U3ppTG0zR0xTOTRLUU9YSmxGSWFoR0JjRmp4b1pUTmNCTFoxaTdBd0RpYmhJLVJyX19qOFkyLW5UUW4wYjBsbTFpa3MzSThqd3pFa0Q0aGZrVWFBWXhMdS1LaUg0R0xRNlB4YUdxb0xVdEtaMm1ld0ZVbi1uMTlGLVN5bDhNakN3czlnQ2ZYZHhFS2hlQ1ByZzNhNHljdFhiOHpJdDg3ZVdyeGFBVW1jdEkxbnJMMUw2WGpQcUFDc0N6WWQtMzhCNTZ0VWtXWnBlRmRIWnl5VkpkeF9XMzZnZG5MWnpoVFNRcGJhTjAxOUNPWkpZeTh6Zk9QQW9paU5IOXVESHgybkRHeUREY1ZCMFBIaVZ2aFN5dFNuWWJZbWJKX1N5dG9LUXl6LVViMzFIWHZURkVVVU1iTl9NdUNiTEwwem9CQ0EtODNyMGJLaGh1bGpXRkFBRWxXR1dTYlNIa3NEenN1NlBid2gxZTUyUFNhem5yVWN4Y0tF&textFormat=plainText&videoId=CJ_GCPaKywg&key=m_developer_key&alt=json",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "user-agent": "google-api-python-client/1.7.9 (gzip)",
    "content-length": "5730",
    "x-http-method-override": "GET",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "methodId": "youtube.commentThreads.list",
  "resumable": null,
  "response_callbacks": [],
  "_in_error_state": false,
  "body_size": 0,
  "resumable_uri": null,
  "resumable_progress": 0
}
```

**NOTE:** I need to have `order= "relevance"` in my request because I primarly need the most voted comments.

An answer is nowhere to be found, I hope you can help me

Comment: `processingFailure` is not [documented](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#BAD_REQUEST)! I don't know if you've came across an API error or a documentation error. This should be reported to [Google](https://issuetracker.google.com). Unfortunate is that, since about two months now, the staff stopped taking into consideration any issue [raised](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).

Comment: May I suggest to try the code (the one using `list_next`) on several different video IDs. Will it be that all your video IDs produce `processingFailure` or just one (or only a few) of them?

Comment: I retract the comment above about `processingFailure` not being documented: found out that in fact it [is](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#youtube.commentThreads.list-badRequest-processingFailure)!

Comment: thanks again for your comments. all my videos, sooner or later, produce a `processingFailure` error. I know such error is "listed" (i wouldn't say documented) but i can't figure out what raises it. "ensure that it is valid": what exactely? when i log the `pageToken` it seems valid, the `videoId` is fixed, what else could be wrong?

Comment: Right now I'm looking at the client code to figure out a way to produce the HTTP headers and body (including the JSON request text) that your `request` constructed for to pass them on to the endpoint.

Comment: I found the method [HttpRequest.to_json](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L1026). Could you please try to use it as `request.to_json()`.

Comment: I successfully paginated (manually, at the `bash` prompt using `wget`) the comment threads of a video having all in all about 80 comments (passing to the endpoint `maxResults=10`). This shows that the commentThreads endpoint is not broken. There is still likely that your issue originates from within the python code itself.

Comment: i've posted an edit

Comment: Please edit out your app key! I'm sorry, I should have mention that you should not post credential data. (Since you made your app key public, by now you should delete it form [Google's developers console](http://console.developers.google.com/), after which ask for a new one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is, we can't really retrieve **all** the comments of every video.

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912604
>   We currently don't support paging through the whole stream. So there's no way to retrieve all the 1000+ commentThreads that you have for that video

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to your problem. It just shows that querying the endpoint via a GET
request method succeeds obtaining from the API the needed page response.

```
# comments-wget [-d] VIDEO_ID [PAGE_TOKEN]

$ comments-wget() { 
    local x='eval'
    [ "$1" == '-d' ] && { 
        x='echo'
        shift
    }

    local v="$1"
    quote2 -i v

    local p="$2"
    quote2 -i p

    local O="/tmp/$v-comments%d.json"
    local o
    local k=0
    while :; do
        printf -v o "$O" "$k"
        [ ! -f "$o" ] && break
        (( k++ ))
    done
    quote o

    k="$APP_KEY"
    quote2 -i k
    local a="$AGENT"
    quote2 a

    local c="\
wget \
--debug \
--verbose \
--no-check-certif \
--output-document=$o \
--user-agent=$a \
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=$k&videoId=$v&part=replies,snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=100&textFormat=plainText&alt=json${p:+&pageToken=$p}'"

    $x "$c"
}

$ PAGE_TOKEN=...

$ AGENT=... APP_KEY=... comments-wget CJ_GCPaKywg "$PAGE_TOKEN"
Setting --verbose (verbose) to 1
Setting --check-certificate (checkcertificate) to 0
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to /tmp/CJ_GCPaKywg-comments0.json
Setting --user-agent (useragent) to ...
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.14 on linux-gnu.

--2019-06-10 17:41:11--  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?...
Resolving www.googleapis.com... 172.217.19.106, 216.58.214.202, 216.58.214.234, ...
Caching www.googleapis.com => 172.217.19.106 216.58.214.202 216.58.214.234 172.217.16.106 172.217.20.10 2a00:1450:400d:808::200a
Connecting to www.googleapis.com|172.217.19.106|:443... connected.
Created socket 5.
Releasing 0x0000000000ae57c0 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /youtube/v3/commentThreads?.../1.1
User-Agent: ...
Accept: */*
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 14:43:39 GMT
Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 14:43:39 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
ETag: "XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/OUAqOrEpA9YYqmVx0wqn9en_OrE"
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 205965
Server: GSE
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,44,43,39"

---response end---
200 OK
Registered socket 5 for persistent reuse.
Length: 205965 (201K) [application/json]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/CJ_GCPaKywg-comments0.json’

100%[==========================================>] 205,965      580KB/s   in 0.3s   

2019-06-10 17:41:18 (580 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/CJ_GCPaKywg-comments0.json’ saved [205965/205965]
```

Note that the shell functions `quote` and `quote2` above are those from [youtube-data.sh](https://github.com/stvar/youtube-data/blob/master/youtube-data.sh) (they are not really needed). `$PAGE_TOKEN` is extracted from the `body` string of the JSON request object posted above.

---

The next question is: why your python code uses a POST request method?
Could it be that this is the cause of your problem?

Comment: The answer to the last question above [is as follows](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L831): when the URL gets to long (in fact it is long since the length of $PAGE_TOKEN is 5572), the client library code makes a POST request instead. It's alright. But we're back to square one!

Comment: thanks, i was just about to comment that the very first request is GET and all the others are POST, even forcing it via `request.method= 'GET'` didn't change anything

Comment: At this stage remains to analize the correctness of lines 832-841 of [googleapiclient/http.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L832). If proven to not be so, then file for a bug report. On the other hand, analizing that code is a bit odd for me, since at the moment I do not have access to a Python installation of version >= 3.

Comment: A immediate analysis of source lines 832-841 I mentioned above, makes me asserting that they are correct. Next thing that comes to my mind is that the API fails at handling long page tokens in the context of POST request methods -- hence the `processingFailure` error returned. This is likely an API bug and should be reported to Google, even if its staff will not take that report into account.

Comment: One more thing: simulating the POST request done by the Python library code (by a modified shell function `comments-wget`), I obtained exactly the same JSON result containing `processingFailure` as you did. This shows that the problem is not with the Python client code, but with the API itself! Please file a bug report, linking it to the things that we uncovered herein.

Comment: [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912604) is the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's Python Client Library [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/plus/plus.py) and to Google's Youtube API [sample code](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/my_uploads.py), you should have been coding your pagination loop as shown below:

```
request = yt.commentThreads().list(...)
while request:
    response = request.execute()
    # your processing code goes here ...
    request = yt.commentThreads().list_next(request, response)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that didn't fix the error

Comment: there's not much more than what i've wrote, but i'll edit