# Youtube v3 API comment retrieval with commentThreads.list endpoint

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using `commentThreads.list` endpoint in Youtube v3 API to get all the comments for particular videos. This works well for us, however, this endpoint requires `youtube.force-ssl` scope which is a pretty sensitive one. The [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) says that this scope is the only option. The issue is that the user gets a warning screen upon connecting the account:
[image]

At this point, users become concerned about the permissions that they are giving to our app, as youtube.force-ssl scope gives the app a bunch of sensitive permissions as "See, edit, and permanently delete your YouTube videos, ratings, comments and captions", according to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Why Youtube v3 API comment retrieval with commentThreads.list endpoint requires such a sensitive scope and is there an alternative way to retrieve all comments for my videos? Now looks like the only option is to get through the [verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en).

P.S. I know that may seem more a discussion topic, however, that looks like an overkill to give such set of permissions to retrieve the information that is available publicly on the page, so I am looking for possible alternatives.

Comment: As far as I know the docs, the API requires `force-ssl` on `CommentThreads` endpoint only for `insert`s and `update`s. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528992/8327971) for a `wget` command on this endpoint.

Comment: @stvar from the answer it is not clear what scope should be requested then. Could you please clarify?

Comment: lopushen: that's why I indicated to read my answer. The endpoint's URL is `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads`. However, I cannot help you much since you showed no code.