# YouTube Data API for getting replies to a comment returns replies in reverse-chronological order

Tags: youtube-data-api

If I got it correctly, when I know a video ID, I use `CommentThreads::list` to get top-level comments, and use `Comments:list` to get replies for any given top-level comment. I called `Comments:list` with the `parentId` set to one of the top-level comment, but the returned replies were sorted in reverse-chronological order. That is, the first element in the `items` array was the latest reply. This is not useful, because both the official Android app or the YouTube website shows comments in chronological order (older replies first).

If there aren't many replies, I could simply get all replies first, and then reverse the array's order. But there could be lots of replies and in that case the result will be divided by pages. I cannot pass the page number, but the `nextPageToken`, so requesting pages in the reverse order (requesting `n`th first, and then `n-1`th, etc) is not possible.

The only workaround I could think of is to get all replies at once and then reverse the order. This could be problematic if there are many replies.

Is this a bug, or did I do something wrong? I could not find any "order" or "sort" parameters in the [`Comments:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) API.

---

PS: It seems I can get replies using `CommentThreads::list` with  `part = replies` the `id = top-level comment's ID`. This works (returns chronological order) when there aren't many replies, but for some reason, the API does not support paging or setting `maxResults` in this mode. The documentation says,

> Note: This parameter is not supported for use in conjunction with the id parameter.

So, I have tested getting replies of a top-level comment with 500 replies. This method returned only the latest 5 replies.

So far, the only workaround I could find is calling `Comments:list` multiple times with `parentId = top-level comment's ID` and `maxResults = 100`, get ALL replies, and reverse the order on the client. Not so scable way, but there aren't many comments with hundreds replies, so, it would work for the time being.

Comment: Indeed the comments API endpoints are kinda weak. For example (an issue which is not documented by the API official docs): the API [may well not return all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072297/8327971) the comments of a given video.

Comment: I saw the linked page. If such limitation exists, I think they should have documented it.  I guess I would have to resort to parsing the YouTube's web page, then. 1000 is not that many, I sometimes scroll down hundreds of comments on a single video.