# Google Apps Script returns an error "Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length"

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

YouTube data api v3 nextPageToken is too long that Google Apps Script returns an error `Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length` when I tried `UrlFetchApp.fetch("requesturl")`;

Here is the request url
`www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key="+API_KEY+"&part=id&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order=relevance&textFormat="plaintext&pageToken=" + nextPageToken`

code

```js
  var API_KEY = '***************************************';
  var VIDEO_ID = 'oG2Ka3nOVzM';
  var maxResults = 100 ; 
  var pageToken = ""; 
  var order = "relevance";
  var textFormat = "plaintext";
  url_commentthreads_1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key="+API_KEY+"&part=id&maxResults=100&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order="+ order +"&textFormat=" + textFormat + "&pageToken="
  var response_commentthreads_1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_commentthreads_1);
  if (response_commentthreads_1.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    Logger.log("Error %s:", response_commentthreads_1);
    return;
  }
  var json_commentthreads_1 = JSON.parse(response_commentthreads_1.getContentText());
  var items = json_commentthreads_1['items'];
  var nextPageToken = json_commentthreads_1['nextPageToken'];
  Logger.log(nextPageToken);

  var length_1 = items.length;  
  var array_1 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < length_1; i++) { //コメントIDの数だけIDの配列を作る
    array_1.push(items[i]['id'])
  }
  Logger.log(array_1);  

  while(nextPageToken != undefined){
    url_commentthreads = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key="+API_KEY+"&part=id&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order="+ order +"&textFormat=" + textFormat + "&pageToken=" + nextPageToken
    Logger.log(url_commentthreads);
    var response_commentthreads = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_commentthreads); //This returns the error "Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length."
    var json_commentthreads = JSON.parse(response_commentthreads.getContentText()); 
    var items_new = json_commentthreads['items'];
    var length_new = items_new.length; 
    Logger.log(length_new);    
    for (var i = 0; i < length_new; i++) { //コメントIDの数だけIDの配列を作る
      array_1.push(items_new[i]['id'])
    }
    var nextPageToken = json_commentthreads['nextPageToken'];
    Logger.log(nextPageToken);
  }
```

Could anyone help to avoid this error?

one of the nextpagetokens was like this.
`pageToken=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`

Comment: What method are you using in YouTube data api v3?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm using list method of commentThreads trying to get all the comment ids for a specific video id. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list

Here is the request URL,
www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key="+API_KEY+"&part=id&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order=relevance&textFormat="plaintext&pageToken=" + nextPageToken

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, the value of nextPageToken is smaller than yours. So I thought that my test might be not correct. Can I ask you about the method for replicating your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike Sure, would you need only video id to replicate? oG2Ka3nOVzM is the id.
In case you need additional info to replicate, please let me know

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In the value length of your `nextPageToken` is 1928. When I tested the video ID of `oG2Ka3nOVzM`, the length was 176. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide the endpoint including the query parameters that you were used? Of course, please remove your personal information like the API key.

Comment: @Tanaike I see, I just added the entire code I run including the endpoint to my question above. Still not sure if I provide all information required though. Kindly let me know if I don't understand your request correctly

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed 3 patterns for avoiding the issue as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If my answer was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue:

From your endpoint including the query parameters, the following results are obtained.

1. `"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key="+API_KEY+"&part=id&maxResults=100&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order="+ order +"&textFormat=" + textFormat + "&pageToken="`

   - This is the endpoint you are using.
   - When above endpoint is used, the value length of `nextPageToken` is 1832.
2. `"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id&maxResults=100&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order="+ order`

   - Removed a parameter of `textFormat`.
   - When above endpoint is used, the value length of `nextPageToken` is 1832.
3. `"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id&maxResults=100&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID`

   - Removed a parameter of `textFormat` and `order=relevance`.
   - When above endpoint is used, the value length of `nextPageToken` is 176.
   - When `order=time` is used, the value length of `nextPageToken` was 172.
4. `"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id&maxResults=10&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID`

   - Removed a parameter of `textFormat` and `order`. And reduced `maxResults` to 10.
   - When above endpoint is used, the value length of `nextPageToken` is 172.

From above results, it was found that when `order=relevance` is used, the value length of `nextPageToken` becomes long.

And in your script, it seems that the length of URL is more than 2 kbytes. I think that by this, an error occurs in your script.

In order to avoid this, how about the following patterns?

### Pattern 1:

Remove the query parameter of `order=relevance`.

### Pattern 2:

Reduce `maxResults`.

- When `maxResults` is 10, 25 and 50 for your default endpoint, the value length of `nextPageToken` is 328, 580 and 1000, respectively.

### Pattern 3:

Use Advanced Google Service instead of UrlFetchApp.

- When YouTube Data API of Advanced Google Service is used, I could confirm that such error doesn't occur. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the internal process of YouTube Data API of Advanced Google Service. So I couldn't obtain the reason that the error doesn't occur. I apologize for this.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable YouTube Data API at Advanced Google Service.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

```
// var API_KEY = '***************************************';
var VIDEO_ID = 'oG2Ka3nOVzM';
var maxResults = 100 ; 
var pageToken = ""; 
var order = "relevance";
var textFormat = "plaintext";

// I added below script.
var json_commentthreads_1 = YouTube.CommentThreads.list("id", {maxResults: maxResults, videoId: VIDEO_ID, order: order, textFormat: textFormat});

var items = json_commentthreads_1['items'];
var nextPageToken = json_commentthreads_1['nextPageToken'];
Logger.log(nextPageToken);

var length_1 = items.length;  
var array_1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < length_1; i++) { //Create an array of IDs for each comment ID
  array_1.push(items[i]['id'])
}
Logger.log(array_1);  

while(nextPageToken != undefined){

  // I added below script.
  var json_commentthreads = YouTube.CommentThreads.list("id", {maxResults: maxResults, videoId: VIDEO_ID, order: order, textFormat: textFormat, pageToken: nextPageToken});
  
  var items_new = json_commentthreads['items'];
  var length_new = items_new.length; 
  Logger.log(length_new);    
  for (var i = 0; i < length_new; i++) { //Create an array of IDs for each comment ID
    array_1.push(items_new[i]['id'])
  }
  var nextPageToken = json_commentthreads['nextPageToken'];
  Logger.log(nextPageToken);
}
```

### References:

- [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list)
- [Advanced Google Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

### Updated: November 30, 2020

In this pattern, stvar's answer and comments were reflected to OP's script. The GET request is converted to the POST request. In this case, API key cannot be used. So the access token is used. In the current stage, it was found that the page token can be directly used.

#### Pattern 4:

```
var API_KEY = '###';
var VIDEO_ID = 'oG2Ka3nOVzM';
var maxResults = 100 ; 
var pageToken = ""; 
var order = "relevance";
var textFormat = "plaintext";
var url_commentthreads_1 = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id&maxResults=100&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order="+ order +"&textFormat=" + textFormat + "&key=" + API_KEY + "&pageToken="
var response_commentthreads_1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_commentthreads_1, {muteHttpExceptions: true, method: "get"});

if (response_commentthreads_1.getResponseCode() != 200) {
  Logger.log("Error %s:", response_commentthreads_1);
  return;
}
var json_commentthreads_1 = JSON.parse(response_commentthreads_1.getContentText());
var items = json_commentthreads_1['items'];
var nextPageToken = json_commentthreads_1['nextPageToken'];
Logger.log(nextPageToken);

var length_1 = items.length;  
var array_1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < length_1; i++) {
  array_1.push(items[i]['id'])
}
Logger.log(array_1);  

while(nextPageToken != undefined){
  url_commentthreads = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id&maxResults=100&videoId="+ VIDEO_ID +"&order="+ order +"&textFormat=" + textFormat + "&key=" + API_KEY + "&pageToken=" + nextPageToken
  Logger.log(url_commentthreads);
  var response_commentthreads = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_commentthreads, {method: "get"}); //This returns the error "Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length."
  var json_commentthreads = JSON.parse(response_commentthreads.getContentText()); 
  var items_new = json_commentthreads['items'];
  var length_new = items_new.length; 
  Logger.log(length_new);    
  for (var i = 0; i < length_new; i++) {
    array_1.push(items_new[i]['id'])
  }
  var nextPageToken = json_commentthreads['nextPageToken'];
  Logger.log(nextPageToken);
}
```

Comment: Pattern 3 works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help! 
I now understand why the token got longer from your investigation. It's really helpful.
>From above situation, it was found that when order=relevance is used, the value length of nextPageToken is long.
Thanks again for your prompt and helpful response!

Comment: @Tanaike: unfortunately you're wrong when saying that *In this case, API key cannot be used. So the access token is used*, when using a HTTP header like `'x-http-method-override': 'GET'` on a `POST` method. No, you're not required to pass an access token: that's because the YouTube's HTTP server that receives that HTTP request does not interpret the request as invoking a `POST` method, but as a `GET` method having the query parameters passed along as the request's body.

Comment: @Tanaike: Please think it again: if the HTTP server would not interpret the request as a `GET` method call, then the whole thing would imply a `POST` method on the `commentThreads` URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads`; this changes the endpoint accessed: [`CommentThreads.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert) instead of [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert). This cannot be so, because it would imply the API to blatantly malfunction.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for comment. From your 2 comments, I think that you are correct. I could understand about `'x-http-method-override': 'GET'`. So I could delete the additional script. And now I could confirm that the 1st suggested script worked again. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Tanaike: Sorry, it seems that I did not made myself clear: your script is OK; only that you are not required to pass on an access token; an API key will suffice.

Comment: @stvar Oh! Thank you for quick reply. I could notice that I misunderstood it. I would like to modify it soon.

Comment: @stvar Now, I found that when I tested the script by replacing the access token with the valid API key, an error of `quotaExceeded` occurs. When the access token is used, no error occurs and the list can be retrieved. The sample of `var VIDEO_ID = 'oG2Ka3nOVzM';` seems the public content. So although I also thought that API key can be used, the error occurred. I would like to check it again.

Comment: @Tanaike: I just retrived all comments (top-level and replies) of the exact same video with my key, and worked OK.

Comment: @Tanaike: I noticed that the `CommentThreads.list` API endpoint's implementation of page tokens has changed. See the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809133); it may well be that the whole OP's issue above is invalidated, since, even on videos that have hundred of thousands of comments, this endpoint's page tokens do not grow wildly.

Comment: @stvar Now, I could confirm that the script worked by the API key and the page token. So I could add the script of pattern 4. And also, I could notice that the page token can be directly used in the current stage as you said. And, I noticed that at the OP's script, the URL of the 2nd while loop is required to add `maxResults=100`. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Tanaike: Sorry for being persistent, but your text *In this case, API key cannot be used. So the access token is used* is still there unchanged; yet the script is not using an access token.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I tested the script of pattern 4, I could confirm that the script worked. So unfortunately, I cannot understand about `In this case, API key cannot be used. So the access token is used is still there unchangd; yet the script is not using an access token.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike: Really no need for apologies. I was saying that your code above does not use an access token as previously did with `var response_commentthreads = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_commentthreads, {method: "post", headers: {"x-http-method-override": "GET", Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});`. That was exactly my point above: there's not need to use an access token since an API key suffices. But (here comes my latter point), your text above still reads like *In this case, API key cannot be used. So the access token is used.* The code and the explanation are contradictory.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for replying. Now I think that I could understand about it. When the post method is converted to get method, the access token is required to be used. But when the get method is directly used for the public content, API key can be used instead of the access token. I could understand like this. If my understanding is not correct, could you please tell me?

Comment: @Tanaike: none of the two cases -- (1) plain `GET` method and (2) `POST` method along with `"x-http-method-override": "GET"` -- are requiring an access token; in both cases an API key suffices.

Comment: @stvar Thank you for replying. I could understand about it. Thank you for my poor skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike: I'm glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem originates from a known issue of the API, which was already uncovered a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516894) on Stackoverflow.

I will summarize the things discovered -- which got [confirmed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912604) by Google staff. You may read all the details on the SO thread referenced above.

- getting the result set from YouTube's `CommentThreads.list` endpoint has limitations by design, since the API breaks, returning error when the `pageToken` gets too long (the length's limit isn't documented at all).
- if a `pageToken` is long enough to make the URL to be passed to the API longer than 2K, then the `GET` method should be replaced with an equivalent `POST` one. To convince yourself, have a look at Google's own public Python [code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/dd49464a6262c0d1f71efcf11f131e2f591fe5f6/googleapiclient/http.py#L880). Things work similarly for any other client library published by Google.