# Why is the YouTube API v3 inconsistent with the amount of comments it lets you download before an error 400?

Tags: python-requests, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am downloading YouTube comments with a python script that uses API keys and the YouTube Data API V3, but sooner or later I run into the following error:

> {'error': {'code': 400, 'message': "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid. Check the structure of the commentThread resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.", 'errors': [{'message': "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid. Check the structure of the commentThread resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.", 'domain': 'youtube.commentThread', 'reason': 'processingFailure', 'location': 'body', 'locationType': 'other'}]}}

I am using the following code:

```
import argparse
import requests
import json
import time
start_time = time.time()

class YouTubeApi():

    YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads'
    comment_counter = 0
    def is_error_response(self, response):
        error = response.get('error')
        if error is None:
            return False
        print("API Error: "
            f"code={error['code']} "
            f"domain={error['errors'][0]['domain']} "
            f"reason={error['errors'][0]['reason']} "
            f"message={error['errors'][0]['message']!r}")
        print(self.comment_counter)
        return True


    def format_comments(self, results, likes_required):
        comments_list = []
        try:
            for item in results["items"]:
                comment = item["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]

                likes = comment["snippet"]["likeCount"]
                if likes < likes_required:
                    continue

                author = comment["snippet"]["authorDisplayName"]
                text = comment["snippet"]["textDisplay"]

                str = "Comment by {}:\n \"{}\"\n\n".format(author, text)
                str = str.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode()

                comments_list.append(str)
                self.comment_counter += 1
                print("Comments downloaded:", self.comment_counter, end="\r")
        except(KeyError):
            print(results)
             
        return comments_list
        

    def get_video_comments(self, video_id, likes_required):

        with open("API_keys.txt", "r") as f:
            key_list = f.readlines()
        comments_list = []
        
        key_list = [key.strip('/n') for key in key_list]
        
        
        params = {
            'part': 'snippet,replies',
            'maxResults': 100,
            'videoId': video_id,
            'textFormat': 'plainText',
            'key': key_list[0]
        }
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
        }
        comments_data = requests.get(self.YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
        results = comments_data.json()
        
        if self.is_error_response(results):
            return []
        nextPageToken = results.get("nextPageToken")

        comments_list = []
        comments_list += self.format_comments(results, likes_required)

        while nextPageToken:
            params.update({'pageToken': nextPageToken})
            if self.comment_counter <= 900000:
                params.update({'key': key_list[0]})
                
            elif self.comment_counter <= 1800000:
                params.update({'key': key_list[1]})
                
            elif self.comment_counter <= 2700000:
                params.update({'key': key_list[2]})
               
            elif self.comment_counter <= 3600000:
                params.update({'key': key_list[3]})

            elif self.comment_counter <= 4500000:
                params.update({'key': key_list[4]})
                
            else:
                params.update({'key': key_list[5]})
            if self.comment_counter % 900001 == 0:
                print(params["key"])
            comments_data = requests.get(self.YOUTUBE_COMMENTS_URL, params=params, headers=headers)
            results = comments_data.json()
            if self.is_error_response(results):
                return comments_list
            nextPageToken = results.get("nextPageToken")
            comments_list += self.format_comments(results, likes_required)
        return comments_list


    def get_video_id_list(self, filename):
        try:
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                URL_list = file.readlines()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            exit("File \"" + filename + "\" not found")

        list = []
        for url in URL_list:
            if url == "\n":     # ignore empty lines
                continue
            if url[-1] == '\n':     # delete '\n' at the end of line
                url = url[:-1]
            if url.find('='):   # get id
                id = url[url.find('=') + 1:]
                list.append(id)
            else:
                print("Wrong URL")

        return list


def main():
    yt = YouTubeApi()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False, description=("Download youtube comments from many videos into txt file"))
    required = parser.add_argument_group("required arguments")
    optional = parser.add_argument_group("optional arguments")
    optional.add_argument("--likes", '-l', help="The amount of likes a comment needs to be saved", type=int)
    optional.add_argument("--input", '-i', help="URL list file name")
    optional.add_argument("--output", '-o', help="Output file name")
    optional.add_argument("--help", '-h', help="Help", action='help')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------- #



    likes = 0
    if args.likes:
        likes = args.likes

    input_file = "URL_list.txt"
    if args.input:
        input_file = args.input

    output_file = "Comments.txt"
    if args.output:
        output_file = args.output

    list = yt.get_video_id_list(input_file)
    if not list:
        exit("No URLs in input file")

    try:
        
        vid_counter = 0
        with open(output_file, "a") as f:
            for video_id in list:
                vid_counter += 1
                print("Downloading comments for video ", vid_counter, ", id: ", video_id, sep='')
                comments = yt.get_video_comments(video_id, likes)
                if comments:
                    for comment in comments:
                        f.write(comment)

        print('\nDone!')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit("User Aborted the Operation")

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------- #


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516894/processingfailure-error-400-while-retrieving-commentthreads-list), it was discovered that google does not currently permit downloading all the comments on a popular video, however you would expect it to cut off at the same point. Instead, I have found that it can range anywhere betweek 1.5 million to 200k comments downloaded before it returns a code 400. Is this to do with a bug in my code, or is the YouTube API rejecting my request as it is clear that is a script? Would adding a time.sleep clause help with this?

Comment: Can you log into a file all the `nextPageToken`s obtained from `CommentThreads.list` endpoint on one of those videos that produces the `processingFailure` error you're talking about? I'm asking you that for to confirm or not that those page tokens slowly get bigger and bigger. (Most interesting would be to also know the page token that generated the error and a few dozens of them prior to the last one.) If confirming that as fact, I'll be able to provide you an answer to your question.

Comment: @Stvar you can download the saved page tokens here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NBBGUI2iwFjYC5ZlzL1JeEL5CcyPlqm0?usp=sharing. I can't see anything particularly out of the ordinary with the tokens, nor do they seem to get progressively bigger.

Comment: Thank you for your work. Indeed all tokens are of length 108. Thus my conjecture is invalidated. When [I investigated this issue in the near past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528992/8327971), the things looked quite differently, since then the page tokens got bigger and bigger, until the HTTP request that the API user issued exceeded an  internal (undocumented) limit, producing an internal error that surfaced to the API caller as the `processingFailure` error that you've encountered. Unfortunately -- due to my conjecture being falsified --, I have no answer to post. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Stvar No worries! Thanks for all your help on this and on my other posts as well!

Answer (score 1):

(I bring forward this answer -- that I prepared to the question above at the time of its initial post -- because my assertions below seems to be confirmed once again by [recent SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66496107/8327971) of this very kind.)

---

Your observations are correct. But, unfortunately, nobody but Google itself is able to provide a sound and complete answer to your question. Us -- non-Googlers (as myself!), or even the Googlers themselves (since they all sign NDAs) -- can only guess about the things implied.

Here is my educated guess, based on the investigations I made recently when [responding to a very much related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528992/8327971) (which you quoted above, yourself!):

As you already know, the API uses pagination for to return to callers sets of items of which cardinality exceed the internal limit of 50, or, by case, 100 items to be returned by each and every API endpoint invocation that provides result sets.

If you'll log the `nextPageToken` property that you obtain from `CommentThreads.list` via your object `results`, you'll see that those page tokens get bigger and bigger. Each and every such page token has to be passed on to the next `CommentThreads.list` call as the parameter `pageToken`.

The problem is that internally (not specified publicly, not documented) the API has a limit on the sheer length of the HTTP requests it accepts from its callers. (This happens for various reasons; e.g. security.) Therefore, when a given page token is sufficiently long, the HTTP request that the API user issues will exceed that internal limit, producing an internal error. That error surfaces to the API caller as the `processingFailure` error that you've encountered.

Many questions remain to be answered (e.g. why is that the page tokens have unbounded length?), but, again, those questions belong very much to the internal realm of the back-end system that's behind the API we're using. And those questions cannot be answered publicly, since are very much Google's internal business.