# How to get more than 2000 comments from video using YouTube API v3

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to get comments from a given video on YouTube using Python.

Based on the examples given at the official website (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), I was not able to get more than 2000 comments.

By one request you can get 100 comments. To get other comments you should use `nextPageToken` from the previous reply. The problem is: `nextPageToken` grows after each request(by ~500 symbols). After 20-th request the length reaches over 8000 symbols and the next request fails. So I cannot make more than 20 requests, which gives me only 2000 comments.

Here is the python code:

```
import oauth2
import time
import urllib3
import json
import requests

def retrieve_comments(params):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads"

    api_key = # Your_API_KEY

    params["part"] = "snippet"  # mandatory
    params["maxResults"] = "100"  # optional
    params["textFormat"] = "plainText"  # or html
    params["order"] = "relevance" # without it sorting by newest

    params["key"] = api_key
    url = url + '?'
    i = 0
    for key, value in params.items():
        if i == 0:
            url = url + key + '=' + value
            i = i + 1
        else:
            url = url + '&' + key + '=' + value
    return requests.get(url).json()

heavily_commented_video = "kJQP7kiw5Fk" # Has over 3 million comments
next_page = ""

for i in range(100):
    response = retrieve_comments({"pageToken": next_page,
                                  "videoId": heavily_commented_video})
    prev_length = len(next_page)
    next_page = response.get("nextPageToken", "")
    print(f"Request #{i+1}: nextPageToken length is {len(next_page)}, "
          f"grew by {len(next_page) - prev_length}. "
          f"Comments parsed {len(response['items'])}")
    if not next_page:
        break
```

which outputs:

```
Request #1: nextPageToken length is 608, grew by 608. Comments parsed 100
Request #2: nextPageToken length is 1120, grew by 512. Comments parsed 100
Request #3: nextPageToken length is 1636, grew by 516. Comments parsed 100
Request #4: nextPageToken length is 2300, grew by 664. Comments parsed 100
Request #5: nextPageToken length is 2632, grew by 332. Comments parsed 100
Request #6: nextPageToken length is 2808, grew by 176. Comments parsed 100
Request #7: nextPageToken length is 3464, grew by 656. Comments parsed 100
Request #8: nextPageToken length is 3804, grew by 340. Comments parsed 100
Request #9: nextPageToken length is 3984, grew by 180. Comments parsed 100
Request #10: nextPageToken length is 4648, grew by 664. Comments parsed 100
Request #11: nextPageToken length is 4980, grew by 332. Comments parsed 100
Request #12: nextPageToken length is 5152, grew by 172. Comments parsed 100
Request #13: nextPageToken length is 5808, grew by 656. Comments parsed 100
Request #14: nextPageToken length is 6144, grew by 336. Comments parsed 100
Request #15: nextPageToken length is 6320, grew by 176. Comments parsed 100
Request #16: nextPageToken length is 6984, grew by 664. Comments parsed 100
Request #17: nextPageToken length is 7324, grew by 340. Comments parsed 100
Request #18: nextPageToken length is 7492, grew by 168. Comments parsed 100
Request #19: nextPageToken length is 8160, grew by 668. Comments parsed 100
Request #20: nextPageToken length is 8484, grew by 324. Comments parsed 100
Request #21: nextPageToken length is 0, grew by -8484. Comments parsed 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to get all 3 million comments from the above example?

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [processingFailure error (400) while retrieving CommentThreads list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57072297/8327971).

Comment: By design, in the case of certain *unspecified* videos (like the one with the ID `kJQP7kiw5Fk`), the API has an *unspecified* upper limit on the number of top-level comments one is allowed to retrieve. This is unfortunate, but a well-known fact.

Comment: You may also read [the accounts on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810000/8327971) I made not long ago.

Comment: @stvar if you retag them google-api i can hammer close duplicates.

Comment: @DaImTo: done that.