# Limit to fetching Youtube Comments

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am attempting to fetch comments from Yotube videos of multiple channels. I know about the Quota limit, of course. Assuming it is set to 10.000 per day and a simple get/list operation costs 1 quota, I am not going to have any problems. My question is: Besides the quota, are there any other limits to fetching Youtube comments that I should know of and would probably encounter?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to [official Google staff statements](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134912604#comment3), the number of items obtained by paginating the result sets of [`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) endpoint is limited.

That limit is not specified, thus one needs to take into account, that, in cases, it will not be possible to obtain *all* top-level comments of a given video. This is unfortunate, but a fact.

Comment: Hi @stvar, many thanks for your response. I saw the note from Google but the staff member did not say if there is a specific threshold for comments and their replies. I am sure they do not just set the limit arbitrarily for each upload.

Comment: @Glorifier: the limit is not arbitrary at all; Google does not document that, but, you may read the following post that uncovered some things from outside the API: [Why is the YouTube API v3 inconsistent with the amount of comments it lets you download before an error 400](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810000/8327971).

Comment: thanks again. The described inconsistency is in line with my observation. From a video with 4000+comments, I have been able to download anything ranging from 400-1500 comments incl. replies. Since we do not have an official statement on the reasons behind that, I guess I have no other choice than to put a disclaimer below my research. Kind of bugs me out, though, that Google won't say anythign to that.