# Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length on GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, url, limit

I'm trying to get some datas from an API, with URL FETCHAPP method, but when i define all the fields that i want to retrieve i have the message :

Exception: Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length.

Do someone know if there is a specific method to shorten the URL ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

If need more details about my issue, please ask it in the comments !

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041429/google-apps-script-returns-an-error-limit-exceeded-urlfetch-url-length check  whether this link is useful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.